# Keypoint orientation in SIFT algorithm?

Tags: python, rotation, scale, invariants

im currently working on SIFT algorithm. i want to ask how do we rotate 16x16 gradient magnitude in difference for 10 degree because the orientation bin 10 degree difference?

and then when we know the maximum gradient orientation example its 200 and then do we rotate -200  or we just input the maximum orientation on database as SIFT feature ?

Comment: Providing a code example of what you have tried so far would be helpful for others to answer your question.

Comment: @vealkind its too long. at least i already done 36 bin histogram and then i want to know how to rotate 16x16 pixel magnitude per 10 degree and how it should be rotate ? should it rotate to minus degree or just take the maximum orientation to be SIFT feature ?